# pyplot - yticks data representation help - need to convert in KB/MB

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to plot graph for throughput numbers.
my data is x axis = time in epoch, y = throughput in bytes.

I have y-ticks as

`print loc, labels
[        0.   5000000.  10000000.  15000000.  20000000.  25000000.
  30000000.  35000000.]<a list of 8 Text yticklabel objects>`

I want to show this data in KB or MB. Please help on how I can go about it?

I am lost and stuck. Currently the data on y starts with 0 -> 3.5 (1e7) which in itself does not make sense about throughput.
So y ticks are - 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5 with 1e7

Appreciate help!

Comment: In addtion the datetime is also showing only hours in format like:   10:41:00:000000 while when I print the numpy array for x-axis I get values in proper datetime format like datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 14, 14, 11, 15)